# How to hide spring data repository functions in service class?

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring data JPA repository, my requirement is when i call repository class methods in service class it should show only custom methods like addUser(X,Y) instead of save().

- Few things i understand, implementation of spring repository is provided by spring framework at runtime, So we cannot provide out own implementation. (This will overhead).
- All methods in JPARepository is public only, so its obivious when we implement this interface all methods will be visible through out.
- I am thinking of using DAO and Repository both at same time. DAO will provide custom function signature and repository will implement DAO interface.

Any Hack ?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want the methods from `JpaRepository` or `CrudRepository`, don't extend those but just [`Repository`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/) instead. It is perfectly fine to have a repository interface like

```
MyVeryLimitedRepository extends Repository<User, Long> {
     User findByName(String name);
}
```

Of course methods like `addUser(X,Y)` will need a custom implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can very well use DAO pattern in this case .

By implementing DAO Pattern in Service Class

1. You create a wrapper between Service and Repository.
2. You can custom code your DAO layer to only expose custom methods to service layer